# С++ Фаил не видит класс из заголовочного файла

Tags: c++, функции, классы

Код отказывается видеть класс и прототипирование функций в заголовочном файле, а так же не может обращаться к функциям в другом файле реализации, хотя открывает их (Если написать название файлов некорректно, то выводит ошибку, что не может найти файл. Следовательно он их открывает).
Суть существования программы в том, чтобы составить класс по определённым характеристикам хим. элементов, занести его в private, а после разделить программу на 3 отдельных файла:
1 - заголовочный
2 - Где хранятся все выполняемые функции
3 - Для функции main

Сам код:

```
//Head.h
#ifndef Head_H
#define Head_H

#include <iostream> // Для cin и cout
#include <math.h> // для математики
#include <string> // текстовые строки С++
#include <locale> // поддержка русского алфавита
#include <cstdlib> 
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream> //файловые потоки

class chemist
{
private:
    string name;
    string symbol;
    int number;
    string type;
    float mass;
    string electrons;
public:
    void read_element(ifstream& file);
    void display();
    float get_mass();
    string get_type();
};

void zadanie1(chemist[], const int, float);
void zadanie2(chemist[], const int N);

#endif
```

```
///Elements.cpp
#include "Head.h"
#include <iostream> // Для cin и cout
#include <math.h> // для математики
#include <string> // текстовые строки С++
#include <locale> // поддержка русского алфавита
#include <fstream> //файловые потоки
#include <cstdlib> 
#include <cstring>


using namespace std; // показывает откуда мы берем функции (cin и тд)
int i;

void chemist::read_element(ifstream& file) // & - адресс
{
    file >> name;
    file >> symbol;
    file >> number;
    file >> type;
    file >> mass;
    file >> electrons;
    file.get();
}


float chemist::get_mass()
{
    return mass;
}

string chemist::get_type()
{
    return type;
}

void zadanie1(chemist aelement[], const int N, float amass)
{
    bool found = false; //bool имеет всего 2 значения false и true
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        if (aelement[i].get_mass() == amass)
        {
            found = true;
            cout << "\nЭлемент с заданной массой:\n";
            aelement[i].display();
        }
    }
    if (!found)
        cout << "\nЭлемент с заданной массой не найден\n";
}

void zadanie2(chemist aelement[], const int N)
{
    bool found = false;
    string atype = "m";
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        if (aelement[i].get_type() == atype)
        {
            found = true;
            cout << "\nЭлемент-металл найдены:\n";
            aelement[i].display();
        }
    }
    if (!found)
        cout << "\nЭлементы-металлы не найдены\n";
}

void chemist::display()
{
    cout << "==============================================\n";
    cout << " Название: " << name << endl;
    cout << " Символ: " << symbol << endl;
    cout << " Номер: " << number << endl;
    cout << " Тип: " << type << endl;
    cout << " Масса: " << mass << endl;
    cout << " Електронны: " << electrons << endl;
}
```

```
///Sourse.cpp
#include "Head.h"
#include <iostream> // Для cin и cout
#include <math.h> // для математики
#include <string> // текстовые строки С++
#include <locale> // поддержка русского алфавита
#include <fstream> //файловые потоки

using namespace std; // показывает откуда мы берем функции (cin и тд)
int i;


chemist* element;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");  // локализация на русский 
    ifstream infile; // файловый поток для ввода данных
    infile.open("element.txt");
    int N;
    infile >> N;
    element = new chemist[N];


    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        element[i].read_element(infile);

    infile.close();

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) // в цикле вызываем метод display
        element[i].display();

    cout << "\nВы бы хотели найти элемент по его массе(1) или вывести все метталы(2) ? (Введите 1 или 2 соотвественно)\n ";
    int choise;
    cin >> choise;
    if (choise == 1) 
    {
        cout << "\n\n Введите искоммую массу ";
        float amass;
        cin >> amass;
        zadanie1(element, N, amass);
    }
    else
        zadanie2(element, N);
    delete[] element;//освобождаем память 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139827/discussion-on-question-by-immoral-comedian-------).

Answer (score 0):

Мне нужно было добавить строчки

```
using std::string;
using std::ifstream;
using std::ofstream;
```

Перед классом в заголовочном файле